# Access violation reading location in C Direct Show

Tags: c, directshow

I keep getting an access violation reading location error in Visual Studio when I execute the code. I also am unable to print the address for troubleshooting. I have no idea what is going on and according to a friend, my code is flawless and that it is a hardware issue. The file seems to be alright so idk if my friend is trolling me or not. My code is here:

```
#include <dshow.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <Windows.h> 

void main(void) 
{
    while (TRUE)
    {
        char SongName[10];
        
        printf("Song name:\n");
        scanf_s("%s", &SongName,10);

        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
        IGraphBuilder* pGraph = NULL;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&pGraph);
        IMediaControl* pControl = NULL;
        IMediaEvent* pEvent = NULL;
        hr = pGraph->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(pGraph, &IID_IMediaControl, (void**)&pControl);
        hr = pGraph->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(pGraph, &IID_IMediaEvent, (void**)&pEvent);

        char SongAddress = (L"C:/Users/Desktop/AudioPlayer/%s",SongName);
        wprintf("%s", SongAddress);

        hr = pGraph->lpVtbl->RenderFile(pGraph,SongAddress, NULL);
        hr = pControl->lpVtbl->Run(pControl);
        FILTER_STATE fs;
        hr = pControl->lpVtbl->GetState(pControl,10000, (OAFilterState*)&fs);   
        if (fs != NULL) {
            printf("%d", fs);
        }
        long evCode = 0;
        pEvent->lpVtbl->WaitForCompletion(pEvent, INFINITE, &evCode);
        pControl->lpVtbl->Release(pControl);
        pEvent->lpVtbl->Release(pEvent);
        pGraph->lpVtbl->Release(pGraph);
        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

Error shows in this line:

```
hr = pGraph->lpVtbl->RenderFile(pGraph,SongAddress, NULL);
```

Comment: `SongAddress`  argument is incorrect, in C++ sense. You'd want to supply the complete hardcoded string as an argument making sure that this is working. also not that you use wrong slashes, path component separators.

Comment: OK, please see this: https://gist.github.com/roman380/6663eb3d3530cee4c3b2d270a0f025a7